# How to prevent hard reloads from bypassing the service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

A hard reload or hard refresh (e.g., shift-reload in Chrome) appears to bypass the service worker.

For example, loading a service-worker controlled page such as https://airhorner.com/ or https://wiki-offline.jakearchibald.com/, setting the network to "offline" in devtools, and then hard reloading the page leads to a broken "there is no internet connection" page. (A regular reload shows the cached page, as expected.)

Is there a way to prevent this, or use the service worker as a fallback in the event that the device is offline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is behavior is explicitly called out as part of the [service worker specification](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-container-controller-attribute):

> navigator.serviceWorker.controller returns null if the request is a
>   force refresh (shift+refresh). The ServiceWorker objects returned from
>   this attribute getter that represent the same service worker are the
>   same objects.

So it's not just a browser implementation detail.

If you felt like there was a strong reason why a service worker shouldn't behave that way, the best approach would be to bring up your concerns in the spec's [issue tracker](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
const installed = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;

if (!installed) {
  const start = Date.now();
  await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');

  // for me it's always 0ms, for the register call to resolve when hard-reloaded
  // but we give it 10ms to be certain
  if (Date.now() - start < 10) {
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

What it does is check if the service worker is installed on startup. If not then it tries to register it, if the register resolves straight away (less than 10ms to be safe) then the page was loaded via hard reload.

If it wasn't installed, and was installed normally then the register call wouldn't be instant